# Conjugation in the symmetric group

Tags: group-theory, permutations, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> Suppose that $\alpha \in S_{n}$, where $n > 2$. Explain why $\alpha(2\enspace 3)\alpha^{-1}=(\alpha(2)\enspace \alpha (3))$.

I know that we should approach this by looking at $\alpha(2\enspace 3)\alpha^{-1}(j)$ for $j$ taking the values
$$
j \in \left\{1, \ldots, n \right\}\setminus\left\{\alpha(2)\alpha(3)\right\},\quad j = \alpha(2),\quad j=\alpha(3).
$$
However I'm not sure how to prove the final result. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try cases:

Case 1: $\alpha^{-1}$ permutes $2$ to $i=2$

Case 2: $\alpha^{-1}$ permutes $2$ to $i=3$

Case 3: $\alpha^{-1}$ permutes $2$ to $i\neq 2,3$

In each case, what does $(2\ 3)$ to $i$ to, what does $\alpha$ permutes the result to.